# Import Data to Salesforce from another sources

Tags: data, import, data-migration

If I have any data that I generate with another programming language, or just data in any text format, and I want to work with this data in Salesforce(It is not any records, It maybe list of some information that I want to have in org) What are my options to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it following these links:
https://www.newfangled.com/things-consider-importing-data-salesforce/

Or you can use Salesforce APIs to integrate your data from your external applications to Salesforce.